# How does a 2d list work in respects to a 2d array?

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim list_ As New List(Of List(Of String))
Dim addition As New List(Of String)
addition.Add("aa")
addition.Add("bb")
addition.Add("cc")
list_.Add(addition)
list_.Add(addition)
addition.Clear()
addition.Add("aa")
addition.Add("hh")
addition.Add("cc")
list_.Add(addition)
For x = 0 To 2
    For y = 0 To 2
        Console.Write(list_(x)(y))
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()
Next
```

Comment: Not sure why the formatting has gone all funny and lost all the line breaks

Comment: Your code highlighting has gone, because you should post some text to your code. Try to edit your question and you will see this error.

Comment: There's no such thing as a 2D list.  A 2D array is a specific thing.  It is a single entity.  A jagged array is an array of arrays.  What you have there is a list of lists, so you could possibly call it a jagged list, but it's not a 2D list as no such thing exists.

Comment: As for the question, what's the question?  Just dumping a chunk of code and asking "how does it work" is not a question for SO.  Please spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to write a good question and then either edit your question appropriately or delete it if it is genuinely off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a List of Lists, but are simply adding the **same** list three times.  Any changes to that list will be reflected in all the copies of that list.

You most likely want to have **different** lists inside your List of Lists.  To do this, you'd have to instantiate a new List with the `new` keyword each time you want start a new list.

Here's an example showing three different lists being added:

```
Dim list_ As New List(Of List(Of String))

Dim addition As New List(Of String)
addition.Add("a")
addition.Add("b")
addition.Add("c")
list_.Add(addition)

addition = New List(Of String)
addition.Add("1")
addition.Add("2")
addition.Add("3")
list_.Add(addition)

addition = New List(Of String)
addition.Add("cat")
addition.Add("dog")
addition.Add("fish")
list_.Add(addition)

For Each L As List(Of String) In list_
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", L.ToArray))
Next
```

Output:

```
a, b, c
1, 2, 3
cat, dog, fish
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this shows things nicely and I now see my misunderstandings